# How to pass a COM object from VBA to C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, excel, vba

I have an Excel/VBA application which outsources the heavy lifting to C++ via a DLL. I currently pass the inputs/outputs between the two using a long list of arguments which are fundamental data types and pointers thereof. I'm trying to refactor the code on both sides to make it more modular and realize it would be helpful to have a common object I can pass across, rather than having to recreate the structure on the C++ side from an unstructured list of pointers.  Thought I'd give COM/.NET a try and this is where I'm at:

1) Created a COM Object using a C# Class Library along the following lines http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12673/Calling-Managed-NET-C-COM-Objects-from-Unmanaged-C

```
// My_class.cs
namespace Interop {
  public interface IMy_class { ... }
  public class My_class : IMy_class  { ... }
}
```

2) Generated `Interop.dll` and registered `Interop.tlb` using `regasm /codebase /tlb`

3) In VBA, add a Reference to the `Interop.tlb`, stuck on trying to pass an instance to C++ DLL function:

```
// VBA
Declare Sub my_func Lib "my_func.dll" (ByRef mc as Interop.My_class)

Sub test_interop()
  Dim mc as Interop.My_class
  Set mc = New Interop.My_class
  my_func mc
End Sub

// my_func.cpp (exports my_func to my_func.dll)
#import "Interop.tlb"

void __stdcall my_func(Interop::IMy_classPtr icp) { ... }
```

VBA seems to create the instance ok but the call to my_func causes Excel to crash. I can see in debug mode that the value of `icp` received from Excel equals `VarPtr(mc)` and not `ObjPtr(mc)` which I believe is the address of the interface. So I tried changing it to `my_func(Interop::My_class* mcp)` and I can at least get in and out of the function without crashing, but it appears there's no functionality available to My_class. The functionality seems to be wrapped in something called `_My_class`, so I tried `my_func(Interop::_My_class* mcp)` but then I crash as soon as I try to interact with `mcp`. Same result with `my_func(Interop::_My_classPtr mcp)`

With the original function, I also tried passing `ObjPtr(mc)` directly to 'icp' using `DispCallFunc` from VBA. Again I could get in and out of the function ok but crashed when I try to interact with the object. Actually I could read from it without crashing (although not the correct values) but got this error when I tried to write to it: `Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually the result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.`

Running out of options here and wondering if I'm even close, whether it's impossible, or whether this is just not the right way to do it.

Note I also tested the C# Class Library directly in C++. I can create an instance using `CoCreateInstance` and interact with it via the interface, so it seems to work ok if initiated from the C++ side.

Comment: VBA is not going to pass you the smart pointer type that the C++ compiler auto-generated for you, this is supposed to crash.  You also can never get a pointer to the object, COM only implements interface pointers.  Something that VBA tries to hide since it has no direct support for interfaces.  Safest way is to declare the argument as `IUnknown*` and QI for the interface.  I think you need to change ByRef to ByVal.

Comment: Ok thanks Hans, I'm trying this. Also wondering if it's going to end up any better than my original unstructured approach ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM and Interop does some internal plumbing which is tripping you up here. I believe you're looking to do something along the lines of:

```
 dim myObj as Interop.IMyClass    # Note: Interface, not the class
 set myObj = new Interop.MyClass
 myObj.name = "My Name"
 myObj.age  = 69
 myObj.job  = "Chief Stamp Licker"

 my_func myObj
```

and then inside my_func:

```
 std::cout << "Name: " << pMyObj->name() << ", "
           << "Age : " << pMyObj->age()  << ", "
           << "Job : " << pMyObj->job()  << std::endl;
```

..and have it print out the information send over.

To do this, you need to enhance your interface to provide 'properties'. You need a get and set method for each property you wish to be able to read or write. This may seem tedious, but there are very good reasons why you want to do this.

Alternatively, you can have handful of methods on your interface which can set a number of properties in one go:

```
myObj.setProperties("My Name", 69, "Chief Stamp Licker")
my_func myObj
```

..which would be easier/quicker for you to implement, but much less flexible and more time-consuming to extend. Something in-between may suit you - e.g. setPerson and setOccupation which take more than one parameter.

The reason you cannot just write directly into myObj's variables is that the 'myObj' in the Visual Basic runtime is *not* the object, it is an interface to a proxy object cooked up by either the Visual Basic runtime environment, the COM subsystem, DCOM subsystem, C# interop layer or some combination thereof, depending on your COM object registration, threading model and how Excel got initialised (which you cannot control).

Comment: Bingo! You made my day :-)))) I actually had the gets & sets set up, I just failed to notice the `.IMyClass` option in the VBE. This is exactly how I was hoping it would work. Looks like my last 2 days of work was not in vain after all. Wish I was in London and could buy you a pint! Many thanks, George